# Is the function of my system a Partial Differential Equation (PDE)?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, laplace-transform

I have a system that aggregates items based on its key (an item is a key-value) that is flowing in it. It aggregates regarding some parameter $L$. For instance, it sums up all items with the same key and emit one item which has a key-value and its value is the sum of all items aggregated.

I have a function that balances the workload of outgoing items based on the key of each item. This function balances using the aggregate parameter $L$. I calculate the balance using the function $L = λ/min(λ)$ ($λ$ is the throughput or number of item per second) which I can also express as $f = x/y$. As you can see I have two variables $λ$ and $min(λ)$ ($x$ and $y$).

The design of my system is expressed in the figure below. $F1$ aggregates the items and emit them to $F2$. The system is constantly monitoring $F2$ to set how many items $F1$ has to aggregate. The function that governs this behavior is defined as $L = λ/min(λ)$.

[image]

The table below exemplifies how I am using the function $L = λ/min(λ)$ to get the value of $L$.

```
+----+---+---------+-------------+
|key | λ  | min(λ) | L           |
+----+---+---------+-------------+
|k1  | 80 |   20   | 80/20 = 4   |
|k2  | 20 |   20   | 20/20 = 1   |
+----+----+--------+-------------+
|k1  | 80 |   20   | 80/20 = 4   |
|k2  | 20 |   20   | 20/20 = 1   |
|k3  | 50 |   20   | 50/20 = 2.5 |
+----+----+--------+-------------+
|k1  | 80 |   20   | 80/20 = 4   |
|k2  | 20 |   20   | 20/20 = 1   |
|k3  | 50 |   20   | 50/20 = 2.5 |
|k4  |200 |   20   |200/20 = 10  |
+----+----+--------+-------------+
|k1  |500 |   20   |500/20 = 25  |
|k2  | 20 |   20   | 20/20 = 1   |
|k3  |700 |   20   |700/20 = 35  |
|k4  |200 |   20   |200/20 = 10  |
+----+----+--------+-------------+
```

I have to derivate my function to use it in the control system. To derivate it I need to know if my function is an Ordinary Differential Equation (ODE) or a Partial Differential Equation (PDE). I believe that it is a PDE because there is more than one variable $f(λ) = λ/min(λ)$ or $f(x,y) = x/y$. Is it correct?

After this, I used the partial derivative technic to derivate it.

$∂f/∂x = x^1/y = 1x^0/y = 1/y$

$∂f/∂y = x * 1/y = x * y^{-1} = x * y^{-1-1} = x * y^{-2} = -x/y^2$

Are my assumptions correct? if so, how do I transform the PDE to an ODE in order to apply Laplace transform on it?

Thanks!

Comment: So we have these "items". An item is described by a numerical parameter $\lambda$. We have a machine called F1. You feed a finite sequence of items into F1, and it sorts them. Somehow this sorting process involves the function $\lambda/\min\lambda$, i.e. for each item dividing its value of $\lambda$ by the smallest $\lambda$ in the input sequence. But how does the sorting work?

Comment: Hi @JackM , there is no sorting. $λ$ is just the throughput of the items. The items are key-value pairs and I aggregate based on the $λ_key$ (i.e.: the throughput of the item w.r.t. the key k.). I decide how many items I aggregate based on the function that I mentioned.

Comment: What is throughput? And what does "aggregate" mean?

Comment: For instance, it sums up all items with the same key and emits one item which has a key-value and its value is the sum of all items aggregated. I also described it on the question.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand a thing. You need to back up and present the problem in a more abstract form that can be understood by people without domain knowledge. I'm voting to put this question on hold for now until it can be rewritten for clarity.

Comment: but I wrote all the details and my question is simple if I am correct to use a Partial Differential Equation (PDE) or partial derivative.

Comment: What is the meaning of $\min(\lambda)$? If $\lambda$ is the current number of items per second, then how do you take a minimum? Is it the minimum over the past ten seconds? Past five?

Comment: no. each item has a key. $min(λ)$ is just the minimal throughput of items w.r.t. the key. This is exemplified on the table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103563/discussion-between-jack-m-and-felipe).